# Adding rectangles to a specific column in a ReportLab table dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

class Rectangle:
def **init**(self, width, height, color, text):
self.width = width
self.height = height
self.color = color
self.text = text

```
def draw(self, canvas, x, y):
    canvas.setFillColorRGB(*self.color)
    canvas.rect(x, y, self.width, self.height, fill=True)
    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 10)
    canvas.setFillColorRGB(0, 0, 0)
    canvas.drawString(x + 2, y + self.height - 12, self.text)
```

def create_rectangle(q_rating):
def get_color(q_rating):
if q_rating == 1:
return (1, 0, 0)  # Red
elif q_rating == 2:
return (1, 1, 0)  # Yellow
elif q_rating == 3:
return (0, 1, 0)  # Green
else:
return (0, 0, 0)  # Black (default color)

```
def get_text(q_rating):
    if q_rating == 1:
        return "Answer Wrong"
    elif q_rating == 2:
        return "Answer Satisfactory"
    elif q_rating == 3:
        return "Answer Good"
    else:
        return ""

color = get_color(q_rating)
text = get_text(q_rating)
rect = Rectangle(50, 20, color, text)
return rect
```

## Loop through each primary skill

for primary_skill in primary_skills:
# Print the primary skill as a string
pdf_canvas.setFont('Roboto-Medium', 12)
#pdf_canvas.drawString(29, y_start, f'Skill : {primary_skill}')
y_start -= 10
q_table_data = [['Skill', 'Questions', 'Ratings', 'Comments']]
# Loop through each skill and check if it belongs to the primary skill or its child skill
parent_skill_printed = False
primary_skill_printed = False
for skill in technical_skills:
parent_title = skill['parent_title']
sub_skill_title = skill['sub_skill_title']
question = skill['questions']
q_rating = skill['q_rating']
q_feedback = skill['comments']
#print(q_rating)
if sub_skill_title == primary_skill or parent_title == primary_skill:
rect =create_rectangle(q_rating)
print(rect)
if not parent_skill_printed:
# Add a row for the parent skill if it exists
if parent_title:
q_table_data.append([parent_title, question, '', ''])
parent_skill_printed = True

```
        if sub_skill_title == primary_skill:
            # Add a row for the primary skill

            #q_table_data.append([sub_skill_title, question, rating_circles, q_feedback])
            primary_skill_printed = True
        elif parent_title == primary_skill:
            # Add a row for the child skill
            #rating_circles = Paragraph(rating_to_circles(int(q_rating)), styles['Normal'])
            q_table_data.append([sub_skill_title, question, rect, q_feedback])

    elif not parent_title and not sub_skill_title and primary_skill == parent_title:
        # Add a row for the primary skill if it has no child skills
        #rating_circles = Paragraph(rating_to_circles(int(q_rating)), styles['Normal'])
        q_table_data.append([primary_skill, question, rect, q_feedback])
        primary_skill_printed = True
```

Problem:
I'm generating PDF reports using ReportLab in Python and need to add rectangles to a specific column in a table. The challenge is that the number of rows in the table can vary, making it difficult to determine the exact coordinates for each rectangle. While I successfully added circles using HTML elements, rectangles don't have direct HTML representation.

What I've Tried:
I attempted to append circles to the table column, but this approach doesn't work for rectangles. In ReportLab, drawing a rectangle requires specifying explicit coordinates, which is problematic when the table has a dynamic row count. Unfortunately, ReportLab lacks a built-in method for directly adding rectangles to a specific column in a table.

Goal:
I'm looking for alternative approaches or workarounds to dynamically add rectangles to the third column of a table in ReportLab without the need for specifying coordinates for each rectangle. Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.